# Getting undefined object in angular in authGaurd

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

When I am writing `console.log(data)` I am getting `username` but when I try to write `console.log(username)` it is giving me `undefined` and returning false each time. I don't know why.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CompaniesService } from '../companyService/companies.service';
import {  CanActivate , Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGaurdService implements CanActivate {
  datas:boolean= false;
  username;

 constructor(private companyService: CompaniesService,
    public router: Router) {
       this.companyService.getUsername().subscribe(
       data => this.username= data.toString(),
       error => console.log(error)
      );
    console.log(this.username);
   }

 canActivate() {
  if(this.username!=null){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to log `data.toString()` ? What is the type of `data`?

Comment: yes i am getting username properly,  shantanukhond this is what i am getting.

Comment: it looks that the assignment is happening after console.log(this.username)

Comment: Try to log `this.username` in the `complete` section of your subscribe:
`(data) => this.username = data, (e) => console.error(e), () => console.log(this.username)`

Comment: but canActivate() {
  if(this.username!=null){
    return true;
  } this should work even after assignment

Answer (score 2):

You know Javascript is Asynchronous. Which means it will not wait for any IO request and keep executing next line of codes. 
The code snippet  you have shared,  `getUsername()` is asynchronous hence JS won't wait for it to get complete and it will execute next line. At that time `username` is `undefined`.

```js
constructor(private companyService: CompaniesService,
    public router: Router) {
       this.companyService.getUsername().subscribe( // <- Asynchrounous call 
       data => this.username= data.toString(),
       error => console.log(error)
      );
    console.log(this.username); // -> executed before service gets the data from server
   }
   
   // modify your code as below  :
   
    constructor(private companyService: CompaniesService,
    public router: Router) {
       this.companyService.getUsername().subscribe( // <- Asynchrounous call 
       data =>{
          this.username= data.toString();
          console.log(this.username); // will print when service gets the data from server
       }, 
       error => console.log(error)
      );
   
   }
   
   // complete work around :
  // you  file  : 
  
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CompaniesService } from '../companyService/companies.service';
import {  CanActivate , Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGaurdService implements CanActivate {
  datas:boolean= false;
  username;

    constructor(private companyService: CompaniesService,
    public router: Router) {
       this.companyService.getUsername().subscribe( // <- Asynchrounous call 
       data =>{
          this.username= data.toString();
          window.localStorage.setItem('username',this.username);
          console.log(this.username); // will print when service gets the data from server
       }, 
       error => console.log(error)
      );
   
   }
 
 
 canActivate() {
    let username = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
   if(username)
     {
       return true;
     } 
     else {
        return false;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: yeh it worked but my problem is not resolving in can active i want to send true if username exist so what should i do?                                                                               
  ` canActivate() {
      this.companyService.getUsername().subscribe(
        (data) => this.username = data,
        (e) => console.error(e),
        () => {if(this.username){return true;}
        });
    return false;
    }`

Comment: You need to apply different approach here.... can you store user name in localstorage ?

Comment: @ShantanuKhond  in which case you are returning false from canActivate(). What is the possible output of username;

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, using *BehaviorSubject* :

```js
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
  ) { }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

```js
export class AuthenticationService {

  userName = '';

  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  isAuthenticated() {
      return this.authenticationState.value;
  }

  async checkUserName() { // use this in your app constructor or ngOnInit
      this.username = await this.companyService.getUsername();
      this.authenticationState.next(this.userName !== null);
  }


}
```

Comment: yes this worked but it works when i press login button second times!